# Xpath for xml search

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml file that I want to search for a word say searchTearm and then want to return names of tags surrounding that search term.
ex :- in below case searchTerm is surrounded by tags namespace, querySubject and queryItem, I am trying to return name of these tags. Name is enclosed in name tag.

Any help with single line xpath for this:

```
<namespace>
    <name locale="en">Test</name>
    <lastChanged>2016-01-12T12:42:46</lastChanged>
        <namespace><name locale="en">Database Layer</name>
            <querySubject status="valid"><name locale="en">qsxyz</name>
                <queryItem><name locale="en">qixyz</name>
                    <>...searchTerm..</>
                </queryItem>
            </querySubject>
        </namespace>
 </namespace>
```

below xpath doesn't seem to work :-

```
/namespace/namespace/querysubject/queryItem[contains(., 'searchTerm')]
```

Comment: 1st, xpath is case-sensitive, so `.../querySubject/...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood correctly

```
/namespace/namespace/querySubject/queryItem[contains(., 'searchTerm')]/ancestor-or-self::*/name
```

selects `name` tags for all ancestor of `queryItem` with `searchTerm`

result

```
Element='<name locale="en">Test</name>'
Element='<name locale="en">Database Layer</name>'
Element='<name locale="en">qsxyz</name>'
Element='<name locale="en">qixyz</name>'
```

if you add trailing `/text()` you will receive not elements but there values

Comment: It is only giving first elements name ie.

Element='<name locale="en">Test</name>'  I want other three too

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=099ff09f-c3d5-415e-9bf6-00a40cbef7d3-xpath